# Moving from one frame to another in JAVA

Tags: java, swing

i want to move form one frame to another in java for example when i press the button ok it will move to another frame in which form will  open. can anyone tell me which event handler am i suppose to use to achieve this in java swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your `actionPerformed` method...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == OK) frame2.setVisible(true);
}
```

If this method annoys you, then I would agree to use one frame with [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Yeah I know there are much better alternatives. This is just the first one that came to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Use one frame. And use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: please tell me how i am not getting it properly??

Comment: @james, That particular layout manager will enable you to swap views. As far as I can tell, there's no need for multiple containers. Use one container and register the appropriate layout manager for swapping. Everything you need to know can be found in that tutorial I linked you.

Answer (score 3):

CardLayout or you can utilize JDialog as well.